# Why is Array.push() throwing an error but Array.concat() does not?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I am trying to add an array to an existing array. The initial data is like this:

```
props: {
ItemData:  // This prop gets populated with data from the parent component. That data comes from a Vuex store.
 {
      type: Array,
      default: null
    }
}
setup(props) {

const Item = ref(props.ItemData);

onMounted( ()=> {
  Form.Title = Item[0].Title
  Form.Files = Item[0].Files
 }
)
}
```

Which results in something like this:

```
Form = reactive({ 
          Title: null,
          Files: [ 
                   {name: "photo", extension: ".webp" size: '1024'}, 
                   {name: "doc", extension: ".pdf" size: '2048'}
                 ]
       )}
```

The data in `Form.Files` comes from a `prop` that is sent to this component from Vuex data:

`Form.Files` may also be an empty array `[ ]` if there are no existing files when the form is loaded.

When the user adds new files, the data for the new files is like this:

```
NewFiles = [
              [
               File, 
               {name: "newphoto", extension: ".jpg", size: "1024" }
              ],
              [
               File, 
               {name: "newdoc", extension: ".docx", size: "2048" }
              ]
           ]
```

`File` is the file object itself as selected via an input field e.g. `<input multiple type="file" />`

So how do we add `NewFiles` to `Form.Files`? I tried the following:

`Form.Files.push(...NewFiles);`

That somewhat works in that the Vue debugger shows the `NewFiles` array added to `Form.Files`, but it thrown an error of `[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.` and the rest of the code fails.

So I tried `concat()` which works:

```
const AllFiles = Form.Files.concat(NewFiles);
Form.BroadcastFiles = AllFiles;
```

There's no errors but I don't understand why `push()` would cause a Vuex error when I'm not touching any Vuex state, and even if I was, why doesn't the `contact()` cause the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.concat` returns a new array with both the current items and the new ones where `.push` modifies the current array instead of returning a new one.

If that array was initially loaded from vuex it results in an unwanted mutation of the store.

Edit:
In the store

```js
mutations: {
    addFile(state, file) {
      state.ItemData[0].Files.push(file);
    },
}
```

In the component

```js
NewFiles.forEach(file => store.commit("addFile", file));
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question to include how the data is populated. It is not directly from Vuex, but via a `prop` that originally gets its data from the Vuex store.

Comment: If you get the data from the store then you should not add the data to that array but add it to the store with a mutation, I'll update my answer with an example

Comment: or take a copy of the array and only adjust that? so `Form.Files = Array.from(props.ItemData)` seems to work

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check this article about the use of spread operator in Javascript, and array reference [How to Use the Spread Operator (…) in JavaScript](https://medium.com/coding-at-dawn/how-to-use-the-spread-operator-in-javascript-b9e4a8b06fab) especially the "**A note about copying by reference**" section. So basically you are mutating the state of Form.Files while using concat and you are losing the reference using the spread operator. One solution can be:

```js
let AllFiles = [...Form.Files];
AllFiles.concat(NewFiles);
Form.BroadcastFiles = AllFiles;
```